# Labeling unique values in R

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr

My data look like:

```
data <- matrix(c("1","install","2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000",
                 "2","install","2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000",
                 "3","install","2015-10-23 14:07:25.000000",
                 "3","sale","2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000",
                 "4","install","2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000",
                 "4","sale","2015-10-23 14:09:20.000000",
                 "4","sale","2015-10-23 14:11:20.000000"),
               ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(data) <- c("id","event","time")
```

I would like to add a fourth column, called label, in which I label accordingly each row on some values. In this case:

- a "0" label if the id is unique
- a "1" label if the id is not unique and it has associated 1 sale
- a "2" label if the id is not unique and it has associated 2 sales

and so on up to n sales.

it should be finally look like:

```
data1 <- matrix(c("1","install","2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000","0",
                  "2","install","2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000","0",
                  "3","install","2015-10-23 14:07:25.000000","1",
                  "3","sale","2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000","1",
                  "4","install","2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000","2",
                  "4","sale","2015-10-23 14:09:20.000000","2",
                  "4","sale","2015-10-23 14:11:20.000000","2"),
                 ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
```

It's not clear to me what's the best approach in R to create "labels" based on conditions... maybe `dplyr::mutate`?

Comment: Note that in your example you mixed "sale" and "sales". Not sure if that is intended or a typo. If that is the case in your real data, you should take extra care of that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Updated to reflect "and so on up to n sales."-requirement.*

A dplyr option could be:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(label = if(n() == 1) 0 else as.numeric(sum(event == "sale")))

#Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
#Groups: id [4]
#
#      id   event                       time label
#  (fctr)  (fctr)                     (fctr) (dbl)
#1      1 install 2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000     0
#2      2 install 2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000     0
#3      3 install 2015-10-23 14:07:25.000000     1
#4      3    sale 2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000     1
#5      4 install 2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000     2
#6      4    sale 2015-10-23 14:09:20.000000     2
#7      4    sale 2015-10-23 14:11:20.000000     2
```

---

The data.table equivalent would be:

```
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)  # or setDT(data) if it's already a data.frame
data[, label := if(.N == 1) 0 else as.numeric(sum(event == "sale")), by=id]
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `as.data.frame` won't convert all of the `character` columns to `integer`/`numeric` as your solution requires.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, not sure what you mean? Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: The code works so downvote removed, but this is encouraging bad programming practice.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, IMO, the `id` and `event` columns are perfectly suited to be `factor` columns, as in the result of my answer. I agree that the time column should be a different (proper) class but that's up to the OP when creating his mvce and not relevant for the question at hand.

Comment: @Frank, I used `set(DT)` after I had already converted to `data.frame` as in the first part of my answer

Comment: The code is incorrect. Try `data[5,2] <- "sale"` and run the function. It returns `"2"`, not the desired output.

Comment: @Frank the instruction to sum up to `n` sales was in the original post. docendo discimus is doing an either or

Comment: @PierreLafortune, not sure what you mean by that last comment. Of course you have to adjust the "sales/sale" typo thing in the data and the code but then it returns the correct output as far as i can tell.

Comment: @Frank, regarding your comment on telling the OP to store their data as data.frame: I agree generally, but it's supposed to be a comment under the _question_ (as there is by now), but not as criticism of my or other people's answers

Comment: For id 4, if all three values were `"sale"`, OP would want `"3"` in the new column. They are not limiting the numbers to 0,1, and 2. Look at the line `"and so on up to n sales."`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune, Correct, I had missed that "and so on" part. Updated my answer

Comment: You could generalize the solution to get what the OP wants by changing `mutate(label = if(n() == 1) 0 else if(sum(event == "sales") == 1) 1 else 2)` to `mutate(label = sum(event == "sales")`. If there are no sales, it'll just come back as 0. (This is untested since I'm on my phone)

Comment: 'sales' was a typo, I edited in the original post. The code in dplyr works but I can have n number of 'sale' occurrences and the label should be taking this into account and increment for each sale

Comment: @VincenzoGrasso, I updated my answer to reflect that. Please check again :)

Comment: @docendodiscimus great! my question now is: what it the best way to now count the id on the basis of the number of sales (ie zero sales, 1, 2 etc) to group by label and count? I would need unique records first

Comment: @VincenzoGrasso, I had to leave my laptop so can't answer that right now. Please ask the complete question upfront in future. Try: `count(data, label)` perhaps

Comment: Why not just use the `table` function? Or if you want it in a data frame, use dplyr: `data %>% group_by(label) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% arrange(label)`

Comment: @brittenb, `count` is a shorthand for that.

Answer (score 4):

With `base R`:

We can use `sum` to tally the occurrences of `"sale"` by `id` using `ave`. Then check that the ids are unique with `uniq`. We assign `"0"` to any unique row. `cbind` pulls it all together. I also converted to data.frame as there is no earthly reason to store mixed information in a matrix.

```
indx <- ave(data[,2], data[,1], FUN=function(x) sum(x == "sale"))
uniq <- table(data[,1]) == 1
indx[data[,1] %in% which(uniq)] <- "0"
cbind.data.frame(data, indx)
#   id   event                       time count
# 1  1    sale 2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000     0
# 2  2 install 2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000     0
# 3  3 install 2015-10-23 14:07:25.000000     1
# 4  3    sale 2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000     1
# 5  4 install 2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000     2
# 6  4    sale 2015-10-23 14:09:20.000000     2
# 7  4    sale 2015-10-23 14:11:20.000000     2
```

Comment: What if `data[1,2] == "sale"`? I think you're simplifying too much again

Comment: That is the correct output. It should return `"2"` for row 1

Comment: According to the `a "0" label if the id is unique`-rule, I would expect a "0" in the first row, regardless of what's in the event column.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes. I'll fix. But you simplified yours too much too lol We'll get it eventually

Comment: Where did I simplify too much?

Comment: @docendodiscimus you are limiting the output to 0,1, and 2. OP wrote those three, but didn't write out every case. Instead they said "and so on up to n sales."

Answer (score 0):

Another dplyr approach for adding columns with summarized values is to create the summarized variable in another table, then join it back to the main data.frame, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(data,
              data %>%
                group_by(id) %>%
                summarise(count = n(), sales = sum(event == "sale"))
) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(count == 1, 0, sales)) %>%
  select(-count, -sales)

> data
  id   event                       time label
1  1 install 2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000     0
2  2 install 2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000     0
3  3 install 2015-10-23 14:07:25.000000     1
4  3    sale 2015-10-23 14:08:20.000000     1
5  4 install 2015-10-23 14:07:20.000000     2
6  4    sale 2015-10-23 14:09:20.000000     2
7  4    sale 2015-10-23 14:11:20.000000     2
```

Comment: You must account for `a "0" label if the id is unique`

Comment: Good catch, it would have been nice if the OP had a row in the data set that met that condition.  Updated my answer to address that.